# An example of prime ideal $P$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n$ is not prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> I am looking for an example of prime ideal $P$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n$ is *not* prime.

In a *Prüfer domain* such an intersection is always a prime ideal.

Comment: A local ring that is not an integral domain? In that case the intersection is the zero-ideal.

Comment: Thank you. But can you give me such example in integral domains?

Comment: Sorry, but I find out that the model in my mind is a discrete valuation ring, which is an integral domain... Sorry again.

Comment: you mean the intersection of all powers of maximal ideals? may be that ideal is idempotent... awllower

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but you demand an example of a non-integral domain, so let me try to find another.

Comment: By [Krull intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin–Rees_lemma), this is not possible in a Noetherian local integral domain.

Comment: So one have to find such example on non-Noetherian domains

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688325/an-example-of-prime-ideal-p-in-an-integral-domain-such-that-bigcap-n-1-i

Comment: Sorry for commenting on such an old question, but why is such an intersection a prime ideal for Prufer domain ?

Comment: This intersection is prime for Prufer domains. For proof see Theorem 23.3 of  R. Gilmer, Multiplicative ideal theory, Marcel Dekker, New York, 1972.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(R,m)$ be a (commutative Noetherian) local ring which is not a domain. By **Krull**'s **intersection theorem**, $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} m^n=0$ is not a prime.

One can use appropriate quotient of local domain to have local ring which is not a domain: $R=K[[X]]/(X^t)$