# An example of prime ideal $P$ in an integral domain such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n$ is not prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

I am looking for an example of prime ideal $P$ in an integral domain such that the ideal $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n$ is not a prime ideal.

This is a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687037/an-example-of-prime-ideal-p-such-that-bigcap-n-1-inftypn-is-not-prime) where the ring was not assumed to be an integral domain.

Comment: What's an example where it's not the zero ideal?

Comment: In order to find such example one should have to find prime ideal $P$ such that $P$ is not idempotent and $\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n\neq (0)$.  So in finitely generated case  we only need to find $P$ such that $\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n\neq (0)$. Because of curse in integral domain there is no idempotent finitely generated ideal.

Comment: For a non-zero intersection, take $D$ the valuation ring of the Hahn series field $\mathbb{Q}[[T^{\mathbb{Z}^2}]]$ with the lexicographical order on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and $P = (T^{(0,1)})$. Then $\bigcap P^n = (T^{(1,0)})$ which is non-zero (but prime...).

Comment: Thank you Captain Lama. In order to understand your example frist I have to understand the Hahn series field $K[[T^\Gamma]]$.

Comment: Captain Lema but I need prime $P$ in an integral domain such that the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n$ is not prime. In your example $\bigcap P^n$ is nonzero prime.

Comment: @TusifAhmed Captain Lama wanted to show that your claim "*in finitely generated case we only need to find $P$ such that $\cap_{n=0}^\infty P^n≠(0)$*" is not correct, the intersection being a non-zero prime ideal. His example also answers the first comment.

Comment: Okay I understand Thank you.

Comment: There are examples of local integral domains $(R,m)$ such that $m\supsetneq m^2=m^3=\cdots$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k$ be any field. Set
$$R = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} k\left[x,\ y,\ x^{1/n} y^{1/n} \right].$$
Each one of the terms in the union is a domain, so the rising union is also a domain. Let $P$ be the ideal $\langle x, y, x y, x^{1/2} y^{1/2}, x^{1/3} y^{1/3}, x^{1/4} y^{1/4}, \cdots \rangle$. Then $R/P = k$, so $P$ is prime (and even maximal).

We have $P^k = \langle x^k , y^k, x y, x^{1/2} y^{1/2}, x^{1/3} y^{1/3}, x^{1/4} y^{1/4}, \cdots \rangle$ and $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} P^k = \langle x y, x^{1/2} y^{1/2}, x^{1/3} y^{1/3}, x^{1/4} y^{1/4}, \cdots \rangle$. So $R/\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} P^k = k[x,y]/(xy)$ which is not a domain, and we see that $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} P^k$ is not prime.

Comment: Note that the rings $k[x,y,x^{1/n}y^{1/n}]$ do not quite form an increasing union: for instance, $k[x,y,x^{1/2}y^{1/2}]$ is not contained in $k[x,y,x^{1/3}y^{1/3}]$.  But there is a cofinal subsequence which is increasing, e.g. those of the form $k[x,y,x^{1/n!}y^{1/n!}]$.